# Sidewinder x6 keyboard macro for Visual Studio?

Tags: keyboard, hardware

the new keyboard from Microsoft, [Sidewinder x6](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/gaming/productdetails.aspx?pid=102) can record in game macro. I was woundering if it could be used in Visual Studio (record key in application too)?

(This could be very useful to press 1 key instead of Ctrl+M,M to Toggle Outline.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES IT CAN!  Sure, why not?  Okay, some reasoning behind my answer.

Just create a "gaming profile" for devenv.exe instead of a game.  BAM!  There you go.

Comment: I'll get it for Christmas, I'll post the answer, if it works, I'll accept you answer ;) haha 2 months later thx :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes its perfect for vs2008. A+++++++++

Answer (score 1):

I have been using side winder x6 and logictech revolution MX for a while with visual studio, I even bought same keyboard and mouse for my work and home. I couldn't go back to normal keyboard and mouse. They both can be assigned to a specific application.

I don't realy use its own build-in macros functionality. instead I assigned them with alot of keystrokes and link to my custom refactoring programs.

Also get a programmable mouse, you can maximise visual studio to a certain level. 
For example, assign CTRL+ALT+SHIFT to one of mouse button, then you just hold the button and press any key. You can produce CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+ [A-Z] keystrokes!!!

Some good programs for you if you bought one. Try them with your own clever ideas, trust me you won't go back to normal keyboard and mouse.

Resharper 
AutoIt3
QMenu
DualMonitorTools